# What environment is used for building the Linux Blender executables?

Tags: linux, development

The Blender precompiled binaries for Linux available at the official download page are said to suit most Linux distributions, with the only requirement of glibc2.11. I'd like to know how are such executables built: With some old Linux distribution?

Or perhaps with a collection of headers/libs that are installed in some custom directory on the build machines just for compiling Blender, even if these machines run a current fully-updated Linux distribution?

I'm asking this because I need a convenient way of achieving the same.

Comment: @veryRandomMe: If you consider building Blender off topic, at least please point me to a forum where users who build Blender from source may have advanced discussions in this topic.

Comment: Does this help? https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems/400#400

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Developing Blender is off topic as per point 4 [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217).

Comment: Yes, feel free to close it, I realized this forum is forbidden to Blender development except Python coding (!). Your site, your rules, don't worry, I'll find a proper place for asking, because, although I believe my question could be useful for other people looking for the same, there're no developers in this audience, so it's not going to get valid answers. So, yes, you're welcome to closing it.